# How to sort two arrays in the same way?

Tags: kotlin

I want output to be: `[3.0, 2.36, 1.1]` of keys and in the same way sorted values `[three, one, two]`

```
fun main() {
    var l = 0
        var letters = arrayOf("one", "two", "three")
        var digits = arrayOf(2.36, 1.1, 3.0)
        var list = mutableMapOf<Double, String>()
        repeat(3)
        {
            list.put(digits[l], letters[l])
            l++
        }

        println(list.toSortedMap(compareByDescending<Double> { list[it]) })
}
```

How can I do that? In my attempt code changes to

```
[1.1, 3.0, 2.36]
[two, three, one]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first make sure `letters` list contain data in correct order, in your question at second position in `digits` you have 1.1 and in `letters` you have two, which seems a mistake to me

```
    var letters = arrayOf("two", "one", "three")
    var digits = arrayOf(2.36, 1.1, 3.0)

    val x = digits.zip(letters).toMap().toSortedMap { o1, o2 -> o2.compareTo(o1)}
    val keys = x.keys.toList()        // [3.0, 2.36, 1.1]
    val values = x.values.toList()    // [three, two, one]
```

if you have large data set and don't want to waste memory on in-flight data structures (`Pairs`, `List` etc) then you can directly build a `SortedMap`

```
val x = emptyMap<Double, String>().toSortedMap{ o1, o2 -> o2.compareTo(o1)}
digits.forEachIndexed{index, value ->
   x[value] = letters[index]
}
```

Comment: Ok, thanks, but I want `[three, one, two]` instead of  `[three, two, one]`. The same way like doubles arranged.

Comment: What if lists had four elements, what output you expect in that case?

Comment: If `letters` list is correct then leave it as it is, the output will be `[three, one, two]` in that case

Comment: Thanks. Didn't notice that it's `var letters = arrayOf("two", "one", "three")`

Comment: I noticed one thing which is not very good. If array of digits contains more than one the same element, only the last of them is visible in `keys`. Is there any way to put all the same elements and leave `letters` elements in it's places in such case?

Comment: I wanted to check your second code. But it says `Unresolved reference: y`

Comment: sorry that is a typo, it should be x. I will update the answer